# Replace value in a configuration file via bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have to replace the numeric values contained into a rhel configuration file through a bash script:

```
auth        required      pam_tally2.so onerr=fail deny=5 even_deny_root unlock_time=600 root_unlock_time=600
```

As long as these values are not the same, I'm unable to match a pattern. How can I find and replace (for example) **unlock_time=600** with **unlock_time=1000**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\(\<unlock_time=\)[^ ]*/\11000/' input_file
auth        required      pam_tally2.so onerr=fail deny=5 even_deny_root unlock_time=1000 root_unlock_time=600
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```sh
sed -rni 's/^(.*\bunlock_time\b=)([0-9]+)(.*)$/\1<PARAM_VALUE>\3/p' <CONFIG_FILE>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a good solution. The only thing is that replace everything in the file and leave only the line that matches the pattern